# Styling a form with two columns

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to re-create this page below

[image: Mock Page]

I am pretty familiar with bootstrap 4's grid system but I struggle very much with forms. Where the form is on the page consists of a row with two col-6. I am working on the first column but I cannot seem to keep everything inline using flexbox classes. Can someone give me an idea of how to get this similar format?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="col-6 d-flex"><!--left side -->
    <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control ml-5">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control ml-5">
     </div>
     <div class="form-inline">
      <label for="month/year">Date of Birth:</label>
      <select name="Month" class="custom-select" class="month/year">
         <option value="january">January</option>
         <option value="february">February</option>
         <option value="march">March</option>
         <option value="april">April</option>
         <option value="may">May</option>
         <option value="june">June</option>
         <option value="july">July</option>
         <option value="august">August</option>
         <option value="september">September</option>
         <option value="october">October</option>
         <option value="november">November</option>
         <option value="december">December</option>
      </select>
      <!--dates in this select below -->
      <select name="Year" class="custom-select" class="month/year">
       <option value="2018">2018</option>
       <option value="2017">2017</option> 
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mt-3">
      <label>Gender:</label>
      <div>
       <label class="radio-button-container ml-2">Male
        <input type="radio" name="radio">
        <span class="black-dot"></span>
       </label>
      </div>
      <div>
       <label class="radio-button-container ml-2">Female
        <input type="radio" name="radio">
        <span class="black-dot"></span>
       </label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="month/year">Field of Study:</label>
       <select name="Month" class="custom-select" class="month/year">
          <option value=""></option> 
         </select>
     </div>
    </form> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-6"></div><!--right side -->
  </div><!-- form for teacher/student-->
   </div>
```

The snippet would be that left side in the first column where "first name" starts. If I can understand how to get that type of alignment then I can figure out the other column. Can this be done using bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is not an [inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms), so you should not use the `.form-inline` class on the `<form>`. This structure is called the Horizontal form and it is described under the [Horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form) section in the Bootstrap docs. Basically you have to use the standard grid classes to layout the labels and input fields as needed.
Furthermore, let your `<form>` tag wrap both the left and the right columns, to create only one form. Otherwise you won't be able to submit it in one go.

The example below provides a sample implementation, where `.col-sm-6` classes are used on the labels, as well as on the inputs.

```html
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6"><!--left side -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="fname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">First Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <select name="Month" class="custom-select" class="month/year">
                                    <option value="january">January</option>
                                    <option value="february">February</option>
                                    <option value="march">March</option>
                                    <option value="april">April</option>
                                    <option value="may">May</option>
                                    <option value="june">June</option>
                                    <option value="july">July</option>
                                    <option value="august">August</option>
                                    <option value="september">September</option>
                                    <option value="october">October</option>
                                    <option value="november">November</option>
                                    <option value="december">December</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <select name="Year" class="custom-select" class="month/year">
                                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                    <option value="2017">2017</option> 
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="gridRadios1" value="male" checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                        Male
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="gridRadios2" value="female">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                        Female
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Field of Study:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select name="Month" class="custom-select" class="month/year">
                            <option value=""></option>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value="email@example.com">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password2" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div><!--right side -->
        </div><!-- form for teacher/student-->
    </form> 
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was very hesitant using two separate forms in two columns but your explanation made a lot of sense!